# mainMixerNode prints an error after recording

Tags: ios, avaudioengine

In my app I do recording and play recorded sound right away:

```
func finishRecording(success: Bool) {
    audioRecorder.stop()
    audioRecorder = nil
    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

    do {
        try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAudioProcessing)
        try audioSession.setActive(false)

        playSound(url: audioFilename!)
```

...

```
func playSound(url : URL) {
    do {

        let engine = AVAudioEngine()
        let newPlayer = AVAudioPlayerNode()
        engine.attach(newPlayer)
        let mainMixer = engine.mainMixerNode
```

The last line prints an error:
ERROR:    [0x1a07d0000] >aurioc> 807: failed: '!cat' (enable 2, outf< 2 ch,      0 Hz, Float32, non-inter> inf< 2 ch,      0 Hz, Float32, non-inter>)

As I understand this error happens because input node is still in use. I'm not sure what should I do to set it free to be able to initialize AVAudioPlayerNode with mainMixerNode?

(If I kill the app and play recorded sound with my play func it works correctly)

Comment: please give your error messages too

Comment: ERROR: [0x1a07d0000] >aurioc> 807: failed: '!cat' (enable 2, outf< 2 ch, 0 Hz, Float32, non-inter> inf< 2 ch, 0 Hz, Float32, non-inter>)